# Minimal way to always have screen on on Android?

Tags: screen

I'm preparing a bunch of tablets using a minimal android OS (https://slimroms.org/).  And was wondering if there's a way to always have the display on (i.e. disable Sleep and Auto Screen lock) without needing to use third party apps.  I've got full root access via SSH and ADB etc - hoping there's some setting in /proc or as a kernel boot argument that I can make.

These are intended to be "We would like your feedback" tablets which are out on public display - so the display should never dim or lock etc. They're always going to be plugged in so power saving etc isn't going to be an issue.

Comment: Looks like WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON could be a possible way (run from a cronjob or service ??) - however, looks like this has been deprecated in API level 27 onwards :-/.

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207081/247431

Comment: Hmmm - a bit hacky but this might work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072501/how-to-unlock-android-phone-through-adb

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the 'keep awake while plugged in' setting
(Screen will never sleep while charging)

Settings - Developer options - Stay awake: on

or from terminal

```
svc power stayon true
```

if the user can press the power button, set the screen lock to "none" (not even swipe) and
use Tasker/MacroDroid/Automate to watch the power button. or run a watchdog from shell

the following example depends on three android binaries
`/system/bin/toolbox`
`/system/bin/toybox`
`/system/bin/input`

```
# (replace first line with while 1)
until [ $(($(toybox cat /sys/class/power_supply/ac/online)+$(toybox cat /sys/class/power_supply/*usb/online))) -eq 0 ]
  do
    case "$(toolbox getevent -lc4 /dev/input/event2 | toybox head -n1)" in
      *KEY_POWER*)
        input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP
      ;;
    esac
done
```

the above code checks for charger is connected as entry point for the loop. the loop exit when charger is disconnected. `/dev/input/event2` may vary for your device. you can check which input event has only 3x buttons [Vol+|Vol-|Pwr] from `getevent -il` (for more generic code look [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=78690858&postcount=354))

Comment: Ugh - maybe spoke too soon.  After a certain amount of time (even with "Settings -> Developer Options -> Stay Awake On") the screen will dim, and dims almost to the point where you can't see anything.  A "tap" will bring the screen back to full brightness - but is there a way to maintain 100% brightness ?

Comment: not sure if there is a keycode for unlock. the only other harmless input event i can imagine is a mouse cursor moving (not touch/swipe) but the cursor might be visible

Comment: Actually another thought I just had - is there somewhere where you can set the "dim" percentage for the display.  E.g. If dim is going to 30% of the total screen brightness, can I set "dim" to 100%.  This way - even if the screen is going into "dim" mode it won't matter (i.e. no need to send 'tap'/'mouse'/'key' events to the display)

Comment: Hmmm - wonder if I can use some of the commands from https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/101 to achieve what I want (via the "adb shell settings put system screen_*" commands).  After looking at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System there seems to be quite a few settings that have been deprecated though.....

Comment: @PatrickRynhart if you use it in kiosk mode with very limited gui, just send a tap to corner every 15 seconds i don't think this harms much (will drop notifications). for more safety you can increase the display timeout up to 30 min and decrease the tap frequency (even tap outside of display will work) `while [ 1 ]; do input tap 720 1260; sleep 15; done`

Comment: Thank you - yes we're using them for kiosks.  Will try this out but this looks like a good workaround.  Thank you - Patrick